# Ajax send image to server

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working phonegap application. I want to send data image to server but i can not sent it.

```
function addSiteToServer() {
    var cId = localStorage.getItem("cId");
    var sname = $('#sitename').val();
    var slat = $('#lat').val();
    var slng = $('#lng').val();
    var storedFieldId = JSON.parse(localStorage["field_id_arr"]);
    var p = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < storedFieldId.length; i++) {
        var each_field = storedFieldId[i];
        var val_each_field = $('#' + each_field).val();
        p[each_field] = val_each_field;
        console.log("p" + p);
    }
    var online = navigator.onLine;
    if (online) {
        var data = {
            site: {
                collection_id: cId,
                name: sname,
                lat: slat,
                lng: slng,
                properties: p
            }
        };
        //function sending to server
        $.ajax({
            url: App.URL_SITE + cId + "/sites?auth_token=" + storeToken(),
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            crossDomain: true,
            datatype: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("data: " + data);
                alert("successfully.");
            },
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the normal method to send data/image to server which is not recommended by Phonegap/Cordova Framework.

I request you to replace your code with the following method which works as you expected,I also used local storage functionality to send values to server,

```
function sendDataToServer(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = {};

    params.some_text = localStorage.getItem("some_text");
    params.some_id = localStorage.getItem("some_id");
    params.someother_id = localStorage.getItem("someother_id");
    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://example.co.uk/phonegap/receiveData.php"), win, fail, options);
}
function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode+"Response = " + r.response+"Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
}
function saveData(){
    sendDataToServer(globalvariable.imageURI);
    alert("Data Saved Successfully");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you your answer. But i don't know why FileUploadOptions is not define. i installed file-transfer already.

Comment: I think you would have missed line for file transfer in XML. Just check your xml file whether you added or not.. Also if you are satisfied with my answer just accept it by selecting the tick mark. Thanks